# Clarification on the hypothesis space of a model

Tags: regression, machine-learning, self-study, maximum-likelihood

I'm self-learning machine learning and deep-learning with the Deep Learning Book from Goodfellow et al. but I'm struggling to grasp the concept of hypothesis space on a simple example.

Let's consider a simple regression model where having inputs x we want to predict y.
So: y = Xw where X is the design matrix and w a parameter we want to evaluate.

In this case, we can say that the hypothesis space of our model is the set of degree 1 polynomial of x.

Now, let say that instead of predicting y, we want to predict p(y|x). Let say our pmodel (our model probability) that we use follows a normal distribution: N(y|x, ^y(x,w), sigma) where y^ is prediction of the mean - our parameter - and sigma the variance (hyperparameter).

If we use the maximum likelihood estimation, we end up to something like:
y* = argmin ||^y-y||2. Once again, if we consider that ^y(x,w) is linear in x, we can replace ^y with Xw as mentioned on the first equation.

My question is, what is the hypothesis space in this case ? In the first case, it was polynomial of degree 1, but now since we have a combination of parameters (i.e. one parameter depending on another parameter) I'm not really sure how this can be interpreted in terms of model hypothesis space.

Comment: Which are the two parameters? I think $W$ is the only one, unless you want to count $\sigma$ as well.

Comment: sigma is not a parameter in this case. In our Gaussian probability model, ^y is the parameter (the estimated mean). And this parameter ^y depends itself on another parameter, W.

Comment: $\hat y$ is not a parameter, it is the output of your statistical model.

Comment: If $\hat y$ is the output of my model, what is p(y|x) then ?

Comment: It is the probability of $y$, conditioned on $x$, as predicted by the model. You can call this the output and $\hat y$ the expectation of the output if you want -- I don't think there's any strict convention.

Comment: In my case, $\hat y$ is an estimator, which has been predicted via my linear model. But I use this estimator to "predict" a probability, p(y|x). So is it not reasonable to consider that we have two models, one for the mean $\hat y$, obtained via the linear model, and another one, outputting p(x|y), obtained by leveraging the MLE ?

Comment: It's a bit weird to think of it that way -- what conceptual clarity do you gain from factoring one model into two models? $\hat y$ is an estimator but not a statistical model because it does not assign probabilities to anything. $y \sim \mathcal{N}(Xw,\epsilon)$ is a statistical model on the other hand.

Comment: Thanks, it makes much more sense now. I was confused because in the book they introduce both models in sequences and when they combine both topics I thought that it was two-models in one. But as a matter of fact, it's just one model, where y is predicted with a gaussian distrib of mean Xw.  Can we then imply that the hypothesis space is all Gaussian distribution with a variance = sigma and a mean equal to a degree 1 polynomial of x ? Please, put your answer in the answer section so I can approve it.